# Caliburn Micro 2 and WinPhone 8.1: Back button not bound?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I'm creating a WinPhone 8.1 app using *Caliburn Micro 2 beta 2*. The app works fine, but I have an issue with the back button in navigation: navigating to another view works, but if I press the hardware back button on the emulator to go back to the previous page once I have navigated, *I'm bumped back to the OS start screen*, as if the navigation stack were empty. In all the code samples I could find it's stated that implementing a `GoBack` method on my VM is enough for binding it to the navigation system via conventions, so it seems I'm not missing anything. If I put a breakpoint on the `GoBack` method but it is not hit at all, which suggests the issue should be rather connected with binding.

Here is a complete repro empty solution: http://1drv.ms/1gLAVil . This app is a sort of CM skeleton with 2 views, so that you can navigate from one to another and then press back.

My relevant code apart from the usual CM plumbing (found in `App.xaml.cs`) is just:

```
public bool CanGoBack
{
    get { return _navigation.CanGoBack; }
}

public void GoBack()
{
    _navigation.GoBack();
}
```

Where `_navigation` is the standard implementation of `INavigationService` injected in the constructor of the base class for all my viewmodels. I tried with both the navigation methods I know of, but (as expected) nothing changes: the method `NavigateToViewModel<OtherViewModel>()` (which has an overload receiving one object parameter whose type should match the target VM's type of a property named `Parameter`, which is a quick way for passing complex objects between viewmodels), and `UriFor<OtherViewModel>().Navigate()` (which builds the URI-like string with optional, simple serializable parameters specified via `.WithParam` before `Navigate()`).

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go back on the click of back button, you need to override the hardwarebutton event:

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if(rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                rootFrame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

Make sure to set e.Handled to true.

Comment: Thank you, I had not realized that CM did not automatically bind the hardware back button.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand.... where? In the code-behind of a View or in the ViewModel ? 10x

Comment: Code-behind of a View.